# filter list in python by another list of stop-words (substrings)

Tags: python

I'm looking for nice pythonic way of filtering one list by another stop-list, but I want to match substrings from second list in first.

To be specific: I have list1 of URLs and list2 like:

```
['microsoft.com', 'ibm.com', 'cnn', '.ru'] etc
```

First list of URLs is huge (thousands of items), second list is smaller, like 500-1000. But simple match using "in" or sets is not enough, because second list items should be used as substring search. 
All I could think is two "for" loops, but they don't seem to by pythonic :)

PS Purpose is to remove matched items from first list.

Comment: Thousands isn't particularly huge. Hundreds of thousands is getting on for huge.

Comment: still takes time.
For example, simple full-string match takes seconds for 2000/2000 lists:
>>> list1 = filter(lambda x: x.lower() not in list2,list1)   
But I need to check for substrings, and can't find effective way like filter()...

Comment: Can you constrain your filterlist at all? Of your example, only one appears not to be an `endswith`?

Comment: no, that's was  example to show that every combination is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a single, disjunctive regular expression from the strings to be matched, then use the `search` method of the RE object to do the matching. Be sure to `re.escape` the strings before pasting them in the RE.

```
>>> import re
>>> substrings = ['microsoft.com', 'ibm.com', 'cnn', '.ru']
>>> pattern = "(?:%s)" % "|".join(map(re.escape, substrings))
>>> print(pattern)
(?:microsoft\.com|ibm\.com|cnn|\.ru)
>>> pattern = re.compile(pattern)
>>> [x for x in ["www.microsoft.com", "example.com", "foo.ru"]
...    if not pattern.search(x)]
['example.com']
```

Comment: This seems to be surprisingly fast. I believed simple strings search to be faster than using re, but this solution takes only 2 seconds for 16000 and 1000 lists. 
I already made something like this for matching two lists but with full match, just joined second list to string and used search, but idea of using re for partial search is nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you expected?

```
one=['microsoft.com', 'ibm.com', 'cnn', '.ru']
two=['.com']
filtered=[o for o in one for t in two if o.find(t)!=-1]
```

Comment: That's not it - I need to filter out items, just leaving those that are NOT in second list, and so I have to check ALL results of .find() and only leave items if all are negative.